# Melhor forma de se aplicar o conceito de Orientação a objetos

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Eu possuo uma classe `Usuario`

```
class Usuario{

}
```

Digamos que esse usuario precise acessar alguns Web Services diferentes para obter recursos e informações. Pensei então em criar uma classe chamada `WebService` e agrupar todos os métodos com acesso a API e serviços externos lá.

```
class WebService {

}
```

A minha dúvida é. O usuário não é um `WebService`, por isso, não posso e nem devo extender essa class. Sendo assim. Qual é a melhor forma de utilizá-la em `Usuário`? Devo criar seus métodos como abstratos e simplesmente usá-los. Ou existe uma melhor abordagem para este caso?

Comment: `$webservice = new WebService()` ?

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira essa é a minha dúvida. Se eu devo tratar assim, utilizando métodos abstratos, ou se existe alguma outra abordagem melhor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma forma é utilizar o conceito de composicão. Se o seu WebService necessita de um usuário para utilizar a API, poderá fazer algo como:

```
class Usuario {...}

class WebService {
    private $user;

    public function __construct(Usuario $user) {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
}
```

E utilizar, em `WebService`, `$this->user` para acessar o usuário em questão. A instância do WebService seria algo como:

```
$webService = new WebService(new Usuario());
```

**Nota sobre interfaces**

Para ficar ainda mais conciso com os conceitos de OOP, ao invés de definir o parâmetro de `WebService` como sendo da classe `Usuario`, você pode criar uma interface:

```
interface UsuarioInterface
{
    public function getUsername();
    public function setUsername($username);    
    public function getPassword();
    public function setPasswrod($passwrod);
}
```

E na classe `WebService`:

```
class WebService {
    private $user;

    public function __construct(UsuarioInterface $user) {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
}
```

O que isso muda? Na primeira solução o parâmetro do construtor deve, obrigatoriamente, ser uma instância de `Usuario` (da classe em si ou de qualquer outra que extenda a classe), mas dependendo da dimensão de sua aplicação, esta limitação pode ser um problema. Na segunda solução, qualquer classe que implemente a interface `UsuarioInterface` pode servir de parâmetro. Esta prática é bastante útil quando for integrar sua aplicação com códigos de terceiros (se for o caso).

Comment: Excelente @Anderson. Era algo assim q eu estava procurando.

Comment: Acho meio estranho um webservice receber um usuário. Talvez o contrário fosse melhor, até porque quem usa algo deve receber esse algo para usar.

Comment: @Piovezan não necessariamente. A lógica que deve ser analisada é quem é composto pelo quê. Um usuário não é composto por um WebService, mas este tem em sua composicão um usuário para efetuar a autenticacão.

Comment: Ah sim, tem razão. Não tinha relacionado usuário à autenticação.